# What LibreOffice (or otherwise installable) fonts are more readable for dyslexic people?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, accessibility

I am writing some study materials in LibreOffice for a dyslexic person, and wondering if there are any particular fonts I can use that will make it easier for him to read the text.

Even if there aren't any specific fonts known to be or designed to be especially readable for dyslexic people, it would be helpful to know what general *properties* of a font make it more or less readable, so that I can make a better choice.

So, what fonts that I can use in LibreOffice are likely to be more readable for dyslexic people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the [OpenDyslexic](https://www.opendyslexic.org/) font.

> OpenDyslexic is a typeface designed against some common symptoms of dyslexia.

It's avaiable in Universe, so you can install it by (if that repo is enabled)

```
sudo apt install fonts-opendyslexic
```

LibreOffice Writer example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There was an interesting literature review on research concerning readability of serif vs. sans serif fonts done some years ago that I've found helpful: "[Which Are More Legible: Serif or Sans Serif Typefaces?](http://alexpoole.info/blog/which-are-more-legible-serif-or-sans-serif-typefaces/)". The conclusion was more nuanced than sans- or serif advocates might have anticipated:

> What initially seemed a neat dichotomous question of serif versus sans serif has resulted in a body of research consisting of weak claims and counter-claims, and study after study with findings of “no difference”....

(The article goes on to reflect on the nature of the research and its findings.)

I'm aware of **two fonts** that have the needs of dyslexic readers and/or legibility as a primary goal:

1. [Andika (New Basic)](https://software.sil.org/andika/download/) - although primarily a "literacy" font, the research that went into the design of Andika [also considered the needs](https://software.sil.org/andika/andika-and-the-visually-impaired/) of dyslexic readers. The font is available in regular-only with a very full glyph set (>  3,800 glyphs), or a more limited glyph set (but still fairly full, 927 glyphs) in a font-family with regular, bold, italic, and bold-italics. The former is [packaged for Ubuntu](http://packages.sil.org/); the latter can also be [found on Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/andika-basic). Andika looks like this:

   [image: Andika sample]
2. [Sylexiad](http://www.robsfonts.com/fonts/sylexiad) - available in both serif and sans serif. These fonts were

   > developed by Dr. Robert Hillier, a semi-retired Senior Lecturer at Norwich University of the Arts. The research involved the design and testing of a new font family developed and informed from a dyslexic perspective against other fonts recommended by dyslexia organisations.

   However, the research itself does not appear to be available. The fonts are available at the link, above, in both serif and sans with a variety of tweaks to width and spacing. They look like this:

   [image: Sylexiad sample]

---

Both fonts are "free", with Andika licensed under the [SIL Open Font License](http://scripts.sil.org/ofl). There is no license I can find for Sylexiad.